# How do I deal with the overwhelming ambiguity of my project?

Tags: phd, advisor

I have a bachelor degree in applied mathematics and I'm currently doing a PhD in molecular genetics as a computational biologist. I started in my thesis lab in January and since then I've had serious problems understanding exactly what my supervisors expect me to do.

Here are a few of the underlying issues:

- I've had to transition from a first principles based approach to problem solving to a top down, data-oriented worldview - something that has not come easily.
- There are no upper-year students doing a project similar to mine that I can shadow while I learn the ropes.
- My supervisors talk about my project and direction at a very high-level, so the details of what I should be doing or how I should be doing them are unclear.
- I face a constant stream of discouragement, be it my peers succeeding while I don't, my supervisors just expecting me to 'figure it out' when it comes to the details, my unsupportive family, etc... and it's affecting my ability to work.
- I did a number of very technical projects in my undergrad and I enjoyed them immensely. I have little love for my current project - likely a symptom of not succeeding.

How do I deal with this? Is it a normal part of the process to feel lost and hopeless - even this early on?

Most importantly: **At what point should I cut my losses and drop out or switch departments?**

Comment: "My supervisors talk about my project and direction at a very high-level, so the details of what I should be doing or how I should be doing them are unclear.".  If you had a clear problem with a detailed path to the solution then this would not be the research. Embrace the ambiguity to show off your creativity.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:health-issues]?

Comment: Have you told your supervisors, explicitly, that you are uncertain how to proceed and you feel you need more more detailed advice in order to make progress?

Comment: @CoderInNetwork How is "Add one drop from one of those colourful liquids to the bacteria stew every day and protocol every slight bit of change" not research?

Comment: @sgf: If there are no decisions to make, you are not doing research.  What you described is being a technician performing grunt work for someone else's research.

Comment: @BenVoigt Let's aks the Oxford Dictionary, shall we? "Research: The systematic investigation into and study of materials and sources in order to establish facts and reach new conclusions." Doesn't say anything about creativity or novel solutions. And by your definition, the moment I've written myself a detailed path to establish some facts, I've  stopped doing research? Grunt work is an integral part of scientific research, and to me at least it constitutes research by itself.

Comment: @sgf: Now you need to ask the Dictionary what a PhD is and how to get one. No idea what it says about that really, but there should be some modifier to research that has at least a relationship to "independent". In short: You are not supposed to have to be told how to do your research in detail any more.

Comment: @sgf: "Grunt work is an integral part of scientific research"... yes, generally, although the amount depends on the field.  "it constitutes research by itself"... most people would not agree, and what is certain is that it conveys no ownership of research.  The rules for patents and the rules for publications agree, authorship and ownership of research goes to the parties who have a hand in directing it.

Comment: @skymningen I certainly don't think it's the kind of research that should earn you a phd or a patent, I was just questoning CoderInNetwork's overly restrictive notion of what does and doesn't constitute research.

Comment: It's not completely clear from your question, but if you are not interested in the specific research topic you are doing, that isn't good. And communication with your supervisors is very important. I'm very familiar with the "talk about my project and direction at a very high-level" issue. To some extent this is unavoidable - your advisers cannot go into every detail with you. But they should also be willing to discuss specifics. I think this is one of those things where it's difficult to say anything even potentially useful without more details.

Comment: To start with, are you interested your research area? Or are you just frustrated because you don't know what to do? Would you prefer another research area? What drew you to this area from applied mathematics, anyway? What do you expect from your supervisors?

Comment: "my unsupportive family" Could you please elaborate, if you find don't mind? I believe this to be a very important point.

Comment: You went from a quite theoretical field to a much "softer" field with much less defined criteria, notions, goals - this is a difficult transition to make. Maybe the topic isn't for you, if it does not inspire you. Half a year is not too long a time to cut your losses. But make sure you identify what you'd rather do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it a normal part of the process to feel lost and hopeless - even this early on?

Yes, it is very normal. Particularly early on. There are many things you do not know or understand yet. I spent at least a year of my Ph.D. on projects that never amounted to anything (literally), and know there were many times I asked myself these same questions.

Now to the more practical question:

> How do I deal with this?

Based on my very similar Ph.D. experience, my best advice is to "own it". You need to convince yourself that *you* are doing the research that will go in *your* dissertation. It will take *you* personally making mistakes and learning from them. It will take *you* developing a workflow where *you* quickly prototype ideas so that the bad ones can be discarded without too much time lost. I would bet that although you feel like you are treading water, you are developing skills and insights that will be useful once you gain more traction.

For this to work, you may need to stop expecting your supervisors' directions. Instead, systematically "try stuff" on your own. Start by addressing some simple concrete question related to your project: try something naive and see why it breaks down. After you identify the flaws, think about and implement some naive modifications. Iterate on this process and document everything carefully. Use your supervisors as reviewers -- explain to them what you did and ask for feedback rather than direction. In my case, iterating this method led to solving a problem parallel to the one my supervisor had original posed, but in a more 'hot' area of research.

Finally, regarding this point:

> I face a constant stream of discouragement, be it my peers succeeding while I don't, my supervisors just expecting me to 'figure it out' when it comes to the details, my unsupportive family, etc... and it's affecting my ability to work.

I often felt deeply discouraged as well. First, comparing yourself to your peers is a recipe for frustration. Avoid this at all costs (easier said than done, I understand). Second, I found exercising, pursuing my hobbies, and meditating all helped curb the day-to-day frustration of the "treading water" feeling.  Talking to other grad students, particularly from different disciplines, also helped. I found this feeling is far more common than some of my peers would let on -- and being able to open up to those a bit removed from your specific project was always helpful.

Comment: +1 for hobbies and exercising. Sitting in the office/lab the whole day and being frustrated can lead to severe health issues if you don't have a good way to come down and relax (talking from current experience here...).

Comment: I like this answer. I would add, in the "How to deal with it" section: Read the relevant literature. Try to summarize it for yourself in 2-5 pages (depending on how much literature). Look at it as a whole and think - what else would I like to know about this topic/biological system? Can my data answer that? Or think, do I find some of the answers given by the literature unsatisfactory/unconvincing? Can my data do a better job answering this? If I think about this another way, might I get a different answer? THEN try things.

Comment: @Dawn Agree completely!